# Should we disable weld subsystem if CDI is not using?

Tags: cdi, wildfly-8, weld

My application is built on JSF 2.2.4 and EJB 3.2. It is not using CDI. Application is running on WildFly 8.2. Should we disable weld subsystem if CDI is not using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me:

```
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
      <deployment>
         <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="weld" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
      </deployment>
      <sub-deployment name="app.war">
         <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="weld" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
    </sub-deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

See More On https://developer.jboss.org/message/851218